# Using pipenv and briefcase, getting AttributeError for pip module

Tags: python, attributeerror, pipenv

I'm attempting to briefcase a hello-world type script, from a virtual environment created using pipenv.  My original python installation building using Anaconda, though I don't really need it as I don't use any of the scientific computing stack.  I am not sure what I'm experiencing is a pipenv error, a pip error, or a briefcase error.  If you could help me sort this, I would really appreciate it.

[Briefcase](https://pybee.org/project/projects/tools/briefcase/)

```
(root) C:\Users\stmwr\Dropbox\SoftwareProjects\helloworld-br\helloworld>python setup.py windows
running windows
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 73, in <module>
    'app_requires': [
  File "C:\Users\stmwr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\stmwr\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\stmwr\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\stmwr\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 973, in run_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "C:\Users\stmwr\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "C:\Users\stmwr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\briefcase\windows.py", line 18, in finalize_options
    finalized = self.get_finalized_command('app')
  File "C:\Users\stmwr\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "C:\Users\stmwr\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "C:\Users\stmwr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\briefcase\app.py", line 123, in finalize_options
    pip.utils.ensure_dir(self.download_dir)
AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'utils'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that this is an issue with Pipenv not supporting Pip 10 yet; in Pip 10, all internal APIs were moved around, which broke all applications that depended on them. I believe the aim is to have a release out [soon](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2013#issuecomment-383102989).

If you can wait a couple of days and then update Pipenv, that will probably be easiest. If you can't wait, you could try to downgrade Pip to version 9.0.3, which should work again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I just nuked my pythonpath and path from orbit, so once I'm finished setting it back up, I will downgrade pip and continue from there.  Whats funny is this is the first time I've ever used virtual environments, and I was doing it so that I didn't get bitten by something like this in the future, and its making a snack of me right now.